# Access violation reading location 0x73726573

Tags: c, arrays, string, fopen, deprecated

I get this strange run-time error and Im not sure how to fix this, I believe this worked for me at one point it is a concordance program, it takes every word in a txt file and puts them in order excluding copies using a binary search tree. first I had to  put in `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE`  because fopen had depreciated and the alt it gave me (s_fopen) was not working. Posted below are my Main and 3 other functions( one to insert in my table, one to print my table then another to empty it) and what the debugger is telling me. Also my main is taking in the table size and txt file from a unix command line.

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#endif
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *Table[60] = { "" };

int insert(char *word, char *Table[], int n);
void empty(char *Table[], int n);
void print(char *Table[], int n);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {


    FILE *file;
    //position in the buffer
    int wordPos;
    //current line
    int line;
    //last character read
    char read[255];
    size_t len = 0;
    //open the file
    file = fopen(argv[3], "r");

    //die if can't open file
    if (!file) {
        printf("ERROR: Can't open file %s. \n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int index = 0;
    //read a char until end of file reached
    int end = atoi(argv[1]);
    while ((fgets(read, 100, file)) != NULL) {
        int k = 0;
        char word[10];
        for (j = 0; read[j] != '\0'; j++) {
            char x = read[j];
            if (read[j] != '\0'&& read[j] != ' ' && read[j] != ',' &&read[j] != '.'  && read[j] != '!'&&read[j] != '?' && read[j] != '\n' &&read[j] != ':' && read[j] != ';') {
                word[k] = tolower(read[j]);
                k++;
            }
            else {



                if (word[0] != '\0') {

                    index = insert(word, Table, index);
                }
                for (k = 0; k<10; k++) {
                    word[k] = '\0';
                }
                k = 0;



            }
        }

    }
    print(Table, end);
    empty(Table, index);
    return 0;

}

int insert(char *word, char *Table[], int n)
{
    int index = -1, k;

    int low = 0, high = n - 1, mid;

    if (word[0] == ' ')
        return n;
    while (low <= high)
    {
        mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
        if (strcmp(Table[mid], word) == 0)
        {
            index = mid;
            break;
        }
        else if (strcmp(Table[mid], word) < 0)
            low = mid + 1;
        else
            high = mid - 1;
    }
    if (index != -1 && index < n) return n;
    for (index = 0; index < n; index++)
    {
        if (strcmp(Table[index], word) < 0)
            continue;
        else
            break;
    }
    for (k = n - 1; k >= index; k--)
    {
        Table[k + 1] = Table[k];
    }
    Table[index] = _strdup(word);
    return n + 1;
}

void print(char *Table[], int n)
{
    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < n; index++)
    {
        printf("%d: %s\n", index + 1, Table[index]);
    }
}
void empty(char *Table[], int n)
{
    int index;


    for (index = 0; Table[index]; index++)
    {
        free(Table[index]);
        Table[index] = NULL;

    }
}
```

This is what the debugger says:

> Exception thrown at 0x0F85C311 (ucrtbased.dll) in CunixProgAssign2ProgTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x73726573.

when I look at the value of argv[3] in the debugger it says this

> - argv[3] 0x73726573     char *

this is what my command lines look like but this is also giving a problem, my permission is denied even though its permission is equal to 777; I figured it was because i cant debug the program without errors.

```
shell:~> gcc -Wall -o concordance concordance.c
shell:~> ./concordance 15 < input.txt
```

the error it is giving me looks like this

```
./:Permission denied
```

For inputs

```
shell:~> ./concordance 15 < input.txt
```

or

```
shell:~> ./concordance 15  input.txt
```

Comment: What is your command line to launch this?

Comment: sorry ill edit and add that~~ Just added it

Comment: Minor idea: Rather than `fgets(read, 100, file)`, use `fgets(read, 255, file)` or even better `fgets(read, sizeof read, file)`.

Comment: BTW: Code can easily overrun `word[]`.  Recommend `word[sizeof read]` and explicitly `word[k] = 0` before `insert(word, Table, index)`.

Comment: @chux Ill try these out once I can get it to run thanks!!

Comment: to get it to run, first compile with all the warnings enabled.  Then fix those warnings.   to help you get started,  the function `tolower()` prototype is missing.   suggest:  add statement: `#include <ctype.h>`

Comment: the posted code calls `_strdup` which I'm not finding on my ubuntu linux 14.04 OS, with gcc.  Perhaps you meant `strdup()`

Comment: there are 7 or so unused variables in the posted code.  signs of 'did not enable all warnings when compiling'.   (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )

Comment: the code should never access any element via `argv[]` beyond `argv[0]` without first checking the value in `argc` to assure the command line actually contains the parameter.  If the parameter was not entered on the command line, then the code will either retrieve a NULL pointer or some random value beyond the end of the argv[] array.   Acting on the NULL pointer or accessing beyond the end of the argv[] array results in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: this line: `int end = atoi(argv[1]);` seems incorrect as this prior line: `printf("ERROR: Can't open file %s. \n", argv[1]);` is using the same parameter for a different purpose.  Then this prior line is also a bit strange and is conflicting: `fp = fopen(argv[3], "r");`   Also, argv[2] is never referenced.

Comment: Strongly suggest the first thing the main() function does (after declaring variables) is: if( argc!=4) { printf("USAGE: %s listOfParameters\n", argv[0] ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); } When ever expecting some input from the user, always check that input for validity

Comment: when a system function returns with an error indication, it is best to call `perror()` immediately, so the associated text and the system error message for the current error are displayed on stderr.

Comment: this line: `Table[k + 1] = Table[k];`  will access beyond the end of the Table[] if the table is full.   This results in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: this loop: `for (index = 0; Table[index]; index++)` will not stop if the table is full, resulting in accessing beyond the boundary of the table, resulting in undefined behaviour, which can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: neither this: `shell:~> ./concordance 15 < input.txt`   nor this: `shell:~> ./concordance 15  input.txt`  match the command line expected by the posted code.

Comment: Note: there is no `s_fopen()` function in the C library in linux.

Comment: regarding this line: `char read[255];`   `read()` is a well known function, prototyped in the stdio.h header file.  it is very poor programming practice to name a variable the same as a system function.   Strongly suggest renaming that variable to something unique and meaningful, like: `inBuffer`

Comment: @user3629249 maybe next time you condense all this ^^^ into an answer its very unpleasant to read in the current format, thanks.

Comment: @user3629249  " `shell:~> ./concordance 15 < input.txt` nor this: `shell:~> ./concordance 15 input.txt` match the command line expected by the posted code." Im aware of this I was had said earlier i was trying to get the former one to work, but i only got the latter one to work.

Answer (score 2):

This: `<` is interpreted by the shell as an input redirection.  It results in the contents of `input.txt` being fed into `stdin`.  It also means that the only argument to your program is `15`.  So `argv[3]` doesn't point to anything, resulting in the crash.

You can call it like this:

```
./concordance 15 not_used input.txt
```

Since `argv[2]` isn't used, you can put any arbitrary string there.

The best thing to do is check that `argc` is large enough, and probably have the program read the filename from `argv[2]` instead.

Comment: Also, check `argc` to make sure `argv[whatever]` exists.  The classic approach is to read from `stdin` if `argc == 1` or  the file named in `argc[1]` otherwise.

Comment: @dbush This may have worked but i cant tell now because im getting permission denied when ever i try to pass it in that way

Comment: @lorehead is that a way  to avoide using fopen ?

Comment: @FelixDaCat If that's the case then the file isn't readable.  You'll need to fix that first.

Comment: @dbush im a little lost here, im not sure whats not readable it compiles fine. Also shouldn't it debug fine before i put any commands in the unix line?

Comment: @FelixDaCat Update your question with the exact input/output on the command line that shows the error.  Also, use `perror` instead of `printf` in the part of your code that checks if `file` is NULL.

Comment: @FelixDaCat No; you’d still use `fopen()` to open the file.  You can pretty much ignore that warning about deprecation in this case.  What I mean is, for most command-line utilities, like `more`, if you give it a filename, it will read that file, but if you don’t, it will read standard input instead.

Comment: @FelixDaCat You might not have permissions on your current directory.  What does `ls -ld .` give you?

Comment: @dbush drwx r-x r-x 2 fff79 users 4096 Oct 23 15:39

Comment: @FelixDaCat And if you run `./concordance 15 not_used input.txt` ?

Comment: @dbush ok I am an idiot, i had an extra space between `./` and  `concordance 15 input.txt` Im new to unix and its a pain getting use to the preciseness. `./concordance 15 not_used input.txt` doesnt work and `./concordance 15 < input.txt` doesnt work. But i think my professor wants  `./concordance 15 < input.txt`